# Regex match file path with or without space

Tags: c#, regex

I am trying to match a path which may contains space and therefore be entered with quote:

```
\-inputfile\s*=\s*'?(.*?)(?=\/|\s|'|\||$)
```

I basically would like to match a string starting with -inputfile= followed by a path between '' or not and stop the match if /,|,or a space or end of line is found.

I ma not sure how to specify hat if the path starts with ' then spaces are allowed and then the match should stop at the next '.

The regex examples are [here](https://regex101.com/r/TWhNmy/1).

Comment: 4 cases you provide in the example, which one is valid? Case 1 and case 2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If i understand from your regex examples correctly, you want to detect all occurrences below:

1. `-inputFile=path/without/space`
2. `-inputFile='path   with/space'`
3. `-inputFile='path/with/single/quotation`

You can use:

```sh
\-inputfile=(('.*')|([^\s]*))
```

***More information:***

*The `('.*')` part matches all characters between single quotes(') and the `([^\s]*)` part will match all characters except space. You need to specify it before `([^\s]*)` part in order to detect 3. occurrence.*

***Much more information:***

*If you do not want to regex to be matched against 3. occurrence (I'm writing it because it is a weird thing to detect) you can simply add single quote to excluded section like that:*

```sh
\-inputfile=(('.*')|([^'\s]*))
```

Comment: Awsome! Thanks a million! Indeed I do not want to capture 3.